# "concat" mode can only merge layers with matching output shapes except for the concat axis

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, convolutional-neural-network, kaggle

I have a function I am trying to debug which is yielding the following error message:

> ValueError: "concat" mode can only merge layers with matching output
>   shapes except for the concat axis. Layer shapes: [(None, 128, 80,
>   256), (None, 64, 80, 80)]

I'm running a kernel from a Kaggle competition called [Dstl Satellite Imagery Feature Detection](https://www.kaggle.com/c/dstl-satellite-imagery-feature-detection) ([kernel available here](https://www.kaggle.com/drn01z3/end-to-end-baseline-with-u-net-keras))

This is the function where I am having issues merging a list of tensors into a single tensor:

```
 def get_unet():
    inputs = Input((8, ISZ, ISZ))
    conv1 = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', dim_ordering="th")(inputs)
    conv1 = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', dim_ordering="th")(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), dim_ordering="th")(conv1)

    conv2 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', dim_ordering="th")(pool1)
    conv2 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', dim_ordering="th")(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), dim_ordering="th")(conv2)

    conv3 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', dim_ordering="th")(pool2)
    conv3 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', dim_ordering="th")(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), dim_ordering="th")(conv3)

    conv4 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', dim_ordering="th")(pool3)
    conv4 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', dim_ordering="th")(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), dim_ordering="th")(conv4)

    conv5 = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', dim_ordering="th")(pool4)
    conv5 = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', dim_ordering="th")(conv5)

    up6 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), dim_ordering="th")(conv5), conv4], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)
    conv6 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', dim_ordering="th")(up6)
    conv6 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', dim_ordering="th")(conv6)

    up7 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), dim_ordering="th")(conv6), conv3], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)
    conv7 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', dim_ordering="th")(up7)
    conv7 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv7)

    up8 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), dim_ordering="th")(conv7), conv2], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)
    conv8 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', dim_ordering="th")(up8)
    conv8 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', dim_ordering="th")(conv8)

    up9 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), dim_ordering="th")(conv8), conv1], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)
    conv9 = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', dim_ordering="th")(up9)
    conv9 = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', dim_ordering="th")(conv9)

    conv10 = Convolution2D(N_Cls, 1, 1, activation='sigmoid', dim_ordering="th")(conv9)

    model = Model(input=inputs, output=conv10)
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[jaccard_coef, jaccard_coef_int, 'accuracy'])
    return model
```

I'm running `keras` with a `TensorFlow` backend. My thoughts are that there are some compatibility issues with versions of software (i.e. the original code is over a year old). Or, perhaps I need to reshape the data somehow.

**What might be causing this error?**

This is the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-e8f13915ac9b>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/aaron/temp/tmp/kaggle_dstl_v3.py', wdir='/Users/aaron/temp/tmp')

  File "/Users/aaron/anaconda3/envs/kaggle-dstl-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/Users/aaron/anaconda3/envs/kaggle-dstl-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/Users/aaron/temp/tmp/kaggle_dstl_v3.py", line 513, in <module>
    model = train_net()

  File "/Users/aaron/temp/tmp/kaggle_dstl_v3.py", line 416, in train_net
    model = get_unet()

  File "/Users/aaron/temp/tmp/kaggle_dstl_v3.py", line 294, in get_unet
    up8 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), dim_ordering="th")(conv7), conv2], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)

  File "/Users/aaron/anaconda3/envs/kaggle-dstl-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/layers.py", line 458, in merge
    name=name)

  File "/Users/aaron/anaconda3/envs/kaggle-dstl-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/layers.py", line 111, in __init__
    node_indices, tensor_indices)

  File "/Users/aaron/anaconda3/envs/kaggle-dstl-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/layers.py", line 191, in _arguments_validation
    'Layer shapes: %s' % (input_shapes))

ValueError: "concat" mode can only merge layers with matching output shapes except for the concat axis. Layer shapes: [(None, 128, 80, 256), (None, 64, 80, 80)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are correct that your code is old as some functions being used are deprecated (e.g. Convolution2D is now Conv2D [see here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/wiki/Keras-2.0-release-notes#layers)).

However, the error clearly states that you are trying to concatenate two tensors that their **dimensions do not match**. When concatenating two tensors along a specific axis, all other dimensions except the one being concatenated must be the **same**. In your case, you are trying to concatenate along axis=1, but the last dimension is different (256 for the first tensor and 80 for the second).

I would recommend basing your U-Net code on a newer implementation ([link1](https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet/blob/master/unet.py), [link2](https://github.com/zizhaozhang/unet-tensorflow-keras/blob/master/model.py), [link3](https://www.kaggle.com/cjansen/u-net-in-keras)).

These implementations replace your

```
merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), dim_ordering="th")(conv5), conv4], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)
```

layers with

```
up_conv5 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last")(conv5)
ch, cw = get_crop_shape(conv4, up_conv5)
crop_conv4 = Cropping2D(cropping=(ch,cw), data_format="channels_last")(conv4)
up6   = concatenate([up_conv5, crop_conv4], axis=concat_axis)`
```

which also crops the height and the width of the previous layer to perform the concatenation correctly (the shape of the crop is determined through an auxiliary function).